# Why is LibSoup not found when compiling Vala?

Tags: programming, vala

I am try to create a application in Vala, but I need `libsoup` and checkout with this command: `pkg-config --list-all | grep soup`. I have `libsoup`, but if I try to compiling with this command: `valac --pkg gtk+-3.0  libsoup  test.vala`, I get this error message: `error: libsoup not found`. My question is what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am being told by people more knowledgable than myself for Vala that your compile command is not quite right. Every package needs the `--pkg` prefix, and you need to specify the full packages name as you have done with `gtk+`.

Something like `valac soup.vala --pkg libsoup-2.4 --pkg gtk+-3.0` should work out a whole lot better for you.

Comment: The part about needing to specify the version isn't quite right.  You need to specify the full package name of whatever package you're using.  Many libraries, such as gtk+ and libsoup, put a version number in the pkg-config name (which is the same as the name of the vala binding), but most do not.  The actual version of the library doesn't always (or even usually) match the version in the package name… `pkg-config --modversion libsoup-2.4` = 2.53.1 here.

Comment: ohh soo simple ^^ thanks
but i have in anjuta the same problem but i add the lib to my project have somebody a good tutorial for anjuta ?